# How to retrieve custom field types for all posts in WordPress/PHP?

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development, custom-field

I have a post type `absf-episodes` copied from the URL `/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=absf-episodes`

The custom fields which I have for the post type `absf-episodes` are:

```
broadview_updated, description_en, description_fr, description_short_en, description_short_fr, episode_id, title_short_en, title_short_fr
```

I have a function in which I want to mention those fields so that I can call the function again and again.

```
function get_down_latest_videos( ) {             


}
```

Posts having **post_type=absf-episodes**: 
 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom fields are saved as "post meta" which is stored in `wp_postmeta`.

To retrieve them, you use the [`get_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) function as follows:

`$value = get_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, $single );`

`$single` will almost always be set to true if you're working string data. Unfortunately, it defaults as false, so if you're retrieving the data as a string, you need to specify this as true:

`$value = get_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, true );`

You didn't really give too much info about the data, but let's assume it's all string data and you want to retrieve it in your function.  Here's your function getting each of these and putting it into an array as a result:

```
function get_down_latest_videos( $post_id ) {             
     $meta_keys = array( 'broadview_updated', 'description_en', 'description_fr', 'description_short_en', 'description_short_fr', 'episode_id', 'title_short_en', 'title_short_fr' );

     foreach ( $meta_keys as $meta_key ) {
          $my_video_data[ $meta_key ] = get_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, true );
     }

     return $my_video_data;
}
```

To use it, if you pass the post ID to `get_down_latest_videos( $post_id )` (where `$post_id` is the ID of your specific post), you'll get back an array with the values of your custom fields where the array is keyed by the post meta key.

**Update:**

Now, if you want to loop through all of the 'absf-episodes' posts, you can set up a query like the following:

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'      => 'absf-episodes',
    'post_status'    => 'publish'
    'posts_per_page' => -1,  // This gets "ALL" instead of limiting the results
));

while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $query->the_post();
    $post_id = get_the_ID();

    // You are now looping through each 'absf-episodes' by $post_id.
    // This example just spits out the post meta results for each post:
    echo '<pre>';
    $post_meta = get_down_latest_videos( $post_id );
    print_r( $post_meta );
    echo '</pre>';

}
```

Depending on where you use something like this, you may need to use `wp_reset_query()` before or after this loop (or possibly both).

Comment: I checked your answer, everything looks good. I have a question regarding the $post_id. I want to retrieve all the posts 
present in the cpac-episodes. https://3v4l.org/DuU85

Comment: For now, I have to retrieve all the posts and then we can all play with the order (ASC/DESC) or with dates.

Comment: There's a lot of "it depends" involved in this because it all depends on what exactly your end result is expected to be.  I've updated with one possibility of a generic example that gets all posts of a custom post type and loops through. It then echos out the array results of the function for each post.

Comment: Makes sense.The custom fields which I want to get for all posts having post type cpac-episdoes are `title_short_en` and `title_en`. At this moment, it is 2 but requirement may change in the future.